# Magento2 : How to add new text field in Store->Configuration->General->store Email Address?

Tags: magento2, system-config, custom-field, system-configuration

Its being created under

> System->Config->General->Customers:

```
<code>
<config>
<system>
        <section id="trade_customer" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Trade Customer</label>
            <tab>customer</tab>
            <resource>Magento_Customer::config_general</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="error_used_message" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Error ID Used Response Message</label>
                    <comment>The error message will display when certificate ID has been previously used</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
</code>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code instead of yours:

```
<section id="trans_email" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <class>separator-top</class>
    <tab>general</tab>
    <resource>Magento_Config::trans_email</resource>
    <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>General Configuration</label>
        <field id="error_used_message" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Error ID Used Response Message</label>
            <comment>The error message will display when certificate ID has been previously used</comment>
        </field>
    </group>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: Not working. Its generating new tab below general

Comment: Check it thoroughly I have changed few things in this xml. Try to copy and paste this to your system.xml. I have changed section id, group id and resource. Flush the cache and test.

Comment: I have applied your code but its not working as its still showing new tab and text field inside it. Store=>Config=>General=>Trade Customer is being displayed now.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot?

Comment: I have attached screenshot in your edit.

Comment: Check my updated code. Its working fine for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95446/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-dinesh-rajput).

Comment: Its working now.

Answer (score 2):

```
<system>
              <section id="trans_email" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                      <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                              <label>Careers Email</label>
                              <field id="careers_email_message" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                                      <label>Careers Email</label>
                                      <comment>The error message will display when certificate ID has been previously used</comment>
                              </field>
                      </group>
              </section>
      </system>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place below code inside the `<system></system>` tag of your custom extension's 'etc/adminhtml/system.xml' file. And you will get your new group(General Configuration) in 'Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses' tab.

```
<section id="trans_email" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>General Configuration</label>
        <field id="error_used_message" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Error ID Used Response Message</label>
            <comment>The error message will display when certificate ID has been previously used</comment>
        </field>
    </group>
</section>
```